# SQL statement to replace multiple values

Tags: sql

I have a table called `paint`, in that a column named `color` is there with two values, either `'Black'` or `'White'`.

I need a single  SQL statement that can replace the value `'Black'` with `'Green'` and `'White'` with `'Red'` in the entire column.

Any help in this will be really appreciated.

Comment: Google for:  SQL CASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case 
when color = 'Black' 
then 'Green' 
else 
    case 
    when color = 'White' 
    then 'Red' 
    else color 
    end
end as [Color]
from paint
```

Answer (score 0):

You update all rows **where** color is black or white. In **case** the color is black you make it green **else** red. Translated to SQL:

```
update paint
set color = case when 'Black' then 'Green' else 'Red' end
where color in ('Black', 'White');
```

Well, I admit, there was not much to translate :-)